# Updating (incrementing) a value within a sub-document in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

If I have a MongoDB collection with documents and sub-documents, as illustrated:

[image]

And, if I want to increment the "damage" by 1 each time the method is called:

```
private final static void incrementCount(String docID, String subDocID) {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", docID);
    query.put("items.id", subDocID);
    BasicDBObject incValue = new BasicDBObject("damage", 1); // or "items.damage" ???
    BasicDBObject intModifier = new BasicDBObject("$inc", incValue);
    badgesCollection.update(query, intModifier, false, false, WriteConcern.SAFE);
}
```

Question: do I refer to "damage" or "items.damage" ?

Comment: `items.damage` is the right way to go. Everything is taken from the root of the document

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Neither.  If you want to increment just the `damage` value for the `items` array element with the matching `subDocID` you need to use the `$` [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#op._S_) to identify that element to the `$inc` operator.  So it's:

```
"items.$.damage"
```