# MongoDB Incrementing Dynamically Generated Sub-Document

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have the document below and I want to dynamically increase the quantity of a specific cart item. Since I don't know the id at compile-time, I can't use the `$inc` operator as you normally would. I was wondering if someone knows how to increase the quantity dynamically. I've got this outline so far.

**Current Progress**

```
function userCartAvail(err, success) {
    if (err) { unableToInsert(); }
    if (success) {
      // 1. Check if user already has that item in his/her cart
      let itemExists = false;
      let cart = success.cart;
      if (cart.length >= 1) {
        cart.map(item => {
          if (itemId == item._id) { itemExists = true; };
        });
      }
      // 2. IF item already in cart, increase the quantity
      if (itemExists) {

      }
    }
  }

  User.findOne({ _id: userId }, { cart: 1 }, userCartAvail);
```

**Document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("587b72870862be18ebc514b1"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    "verified" : false,
    "dateCreated" : ISODate("2017-01-15T13:00:55.335Z"),
    "cart" : [ 
        {
            "quantity" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("587b6b69799ad7ff650edbb5")
        }, 
        {
            "quantity" : 1,
            "_id" : ObjectId("587b6bedbb5")
        }, 
    ]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating (incrementing) a value within a sub-document in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536644/updating-incrementing-a-value-within-a-sub-document-in-mongodb)

Comment: You say that _I want to dynamically increase the quantity of a specific cart item_, how do you identify that _specific_ item?

Comment: so I'm identifying that item using the `_id` property within each cart object.

Comment: If you have the `itemId` then your update should be `User.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": userId, "cart._id": itemId }, { "$inc": { "cart.$.quantity": 1 } }, { "new": true }, callback);`

Comment: cool! I'll give that a go and report back :)

Comment: awesome! that works for me. Do you want to put it in an answer so I can accept?